# Sorting multidim array: prioritize if column contains substring, then order by a second column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, usort

I am currently creating a sorting method that consists of values from an mysql query.

Here's a brief view of the array:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['id'] = 1;
                ['countries'] = 'EN,CH,SP';
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                ['id'] = 2;
                ['countries'] = 'GE,SP,SV';
            )
    )
```

I have succeeded in making a normal usort based on the numeric id values, but I rather want to sort the array by the content of the "countries" field (if it contains a set string, a country code in this case), and then by the id field.

The following snippet was my first idea of how to do it, but I have no idea of how to incorporate it into an working function:

```
in_array('EN', explode(",",$a['countries']) );
```

How would you do it?

Thanks!

---

I am really getting nowhere with this unfortunately.

Here is what I have for the moment, and its giving me nothing but errors: `uasort() [function.uasort]: Invalid comparison function`

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    global $usercountry;

        if ( in_array($usercountry, $a['countries']) && in_array($usercountry, $a['countries']) ) {
            $return = 0;
        }

        else if (in_array($usercountry, $a['countries'])) {
            $return = 1;
        }

        else {
            $return = -1;
        }

        return $return;


        }

        $array= usort($array, "compare");
```

Is there anyone who might give me a hint of how to go on with it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you get them sorted out of the DB in the first place, e.g. `ORDER BY country, id`

Comment: Its already sorted by ID in the first place, as you say, but that doesn't solve the in_array-part of the issue though...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I would use a custom (anonymous) function in conjunction with [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

EDIT: Re - your comment.  Hopefully this will put you on the right track.  This function gives equal priority to elements which both have EN or neither have EN, or adjusted priority when just one has EN.

```
usort($array,function ($a, $b) {
    $ac = strpos($a['countries'],'EN');
    $bc = strpos($b['countries'],'EN');
    if (($ac !== false && $bc !== false) || ($ac == false && $bc == false)) {
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($ac !== false) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

This function, on the other hand, gives equal priority if both have EN, higher if one has EN, and does a text comparison if neither has EN.

```
usort($array,function ($a, $b) {
    $ac = strpos($a['countries'],'EN');
    $bc = strpos($b['countries'],'EN');
    if ($ac !== false && $bc !== false)) {
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($ac !== false) {
        return 1;
    }
    elseif ($bc !== false) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        if ($a['countries'] == $b['countries']) {
            return 0;
        }
        elseif($a['countries'] > $b['countries']) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
});
```

Again, hopefully this will give you enough direction to move forward on your own.  If you are having any problems, feel free to post more comments and I'll try to help.  <s>A note if you're tying to compare multiple properties with weight: try out a funky switch block, e.g.</s>

```
$ac = array_flip(explode(',',$a['countries']));
$bc = array_flip(explode(',',$b['countries']));
switch (true) {
    case array_key_exists('EN',$ac) && !array_key_exists('EN',$bc):
        return 1;
    case array_key_exists('DE',$ac) && !array_key_exists('EN',$bc) && !array_key_exists('EN',$bc):
        return 1;
    // and so on
}
```

#More Edits!#
Actually, I was thinking more on the problem of complex sorting, and I have come up with the following solution, for your consideration.  It will allow you to define numerical rankings based on keywords which would appear in the countries index.  Here is the code, including an example:

**Example Array**

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'countries' => 'EN,DE,SP',
    ),
    array(
        'countries' => 'EN,CH,SP',
    ),
    array(
        'countries' => 'DE,SP,CH',
    ),
    array(
        'countries' => 'DE,SV,SP',
    ),
    array(
        'countries' => 'EN,SP,FR',
    ),
    array(
        'countries' => 'DE,FR,CH',
    ),
    array(
        'countries' => 'CH,EN,SP',
    ),

);
```

**Sorting Routine**

```
$rankings = array(
    'EN' => 10,
    'SP' => 8,
    'FR' => 7,
    'DE' => 5,
    'CH' => 3,
    'SV' => 1,
);
usort($array, function (&$a, &$b) use ($rankings) {
    if (isset($a['_score'])) {
        $aScore = $a['_score'];
    }
    else {
        $aScore = 0;
        $aCountries = explode(',',$a['countries']);
        foreach ($aCountries as $country) {
            if (isset($rankings[$country])) {
                $aScore += $rankings[$country];
            }
        }
        $a['_score'] = $aScore;
    }

    if (isset($b['_score'])) {
        $bScore = $b['_score'];
    }
    else {
        $bScore = 0;
        $bCountries = explode(',',$b['countries']);
        foreach ($bCountries as $country) {
            if (isset($rankings[$country])) {
                $bScore += $rankings[$country];
            }
        }
        $b['_score'] = $bScore;
    }
    if ($aScore == $bScore) {
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($aScore > $bScore) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Note: This code will sort the **highest ranking entires to the top of the array**.  If you want reverse behavior, change this:

```
    elseif ($aScore > $bScore) {
```

to

```
    elseif ($aScore < $bScore) {
```

Note that the greater-than was changed to a less-than symbol.  Making this change will result in the **lowest ranking entries being sorted to the top of the array**.  Hope all this helps!

##NOTE ALSO!##
This code will make a small change to your array, in that it adds the _score element to each array.  Hopefully this is not a problem, as by storing this value I was literally able to increase speed by more than double (.00038-.00041 down to .00016-.00018 in my benchmarks).  If not, remove the `if` blocks that retrieve the cached value and let the contents of the `else` blocks execute every time, except of course for the part which stores the score value.

By the way, here's a `var_export()` dump of the array after it was sorted:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    'countries' => 'EN,SP,FR',
    '_score' => 25,
  ),
  1 => array (
    'countries' => 'EN,DE,SP',
    '_score' => 23,
  ),
  2 => array (
    'countries' => 'EN,CH,SP',
    '_score' => 21,
  ),
  3 => array (
    'countries' => 'CH,EN,SP',
    '_score' => 21,
  ),
  4 => array (
    'countries' => 'DE,SP,CH',
    '_score' => 16,
  ),
  5 => array (
    'countries' => 'DE,FR,CH',
    '_score' => 15,
  ),
  6 => array (
    'countries' => 'DE,SV,SP',
    '_score' => 14,
  ),
)
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Finally found this wonderful function at PHP.net:

```
        function array_msort($array, $cols)
        {
            $colarr = array();
            foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
                $colarr[$col] = array();
                foreach ($array as $k => $row) { $colarr[$col]['_'.$k] = strtolower($row[$col]); }
            }
            $eval = 'array_multisort(';
            foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
                $eval .= '$colarr[\''.$col.'\'],'.$order.',';
            }
            $eval = substr($eval,0,-1).');';
            eval($eval);
            $ret = array();
            foreach ($colarr as $col => $arr) {
                foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
                    $k = substr($k,1);
                    if (!isset($ret[$k])) $ret[$k] = $array[$k];
                    $ret[$k][$col] = $array[$k][$col];
                }
            }
            return $ret;

        }
```

This is how each country looks like:
$array['countries'] = in_array($needle, $haystack);
                        }

```
$array = $array = array_msort($array, array('countries'=>SORT_DESC, 'id'=>SORT_ASC));
```

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Yikes...  `eval()`?  Entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [`array_walk_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), which when combined together maybe to get to doing what you want to do.

Comment: This "hint" could have been a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently creating a sorting method that consists of values from an mysql query.

**TRUTH:**
 Using anything other than MySQL to sort your result set will be less efficient (with php, a `usort()` or `array_multisort()` call will be more convoluted and harder to maintain) and therefore inappropriate.

SQL: ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/frQ5MHyeh4MAsA7e6GgCY4/0))

```
ORDER BY IF(LOCATE('EN', countries), 0, 1), id;
```

This prioritizes `countries` column values that contain `EN` then sorts on `id` ASC.

---

For anyone who isn't handling a sql result set or cannot manipulate the query for some reason, I endorse `usort()`.
PHP7 offers a beautiful new operator that performs a comparison and returns one of three values (-1, 0, 1). This operator is affectionately called the "spaceship operator" and looks like this `<=>`.

PHP: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GoVhs))

```
$test = [
    ['id' => 1, 'countries' => 'EN,CH,SP'],
    ['id' => 2, 'countries' => 'GE,SP,SV'],
    ['id' => 3, 'countries' => 'PR,SP,IT'],
    ['id' => 4, 'countries' => 'EN'],
    ['id' => 5, 'countries' => 'SP,EN'],
    ['id' => 6, 'countries' => 'SV,SP,EN'],
    ['id' => 7, 'countries' => 'GE,SP'],
    ['id' => 8, 'countries' => 'FR'],
    ['id' => 9, 'countries' => 'RU,EN'],
    ['id' => 10, 'countries' => 'EN,SP,IT'],
    ['id' => 11, 'countries' => 'SP,GR'],
    ['id' => 12, 'countries' => 'GR,EN']
];

usort($test, function($a, $b) {
    return [strpos($a['countries'], 'EN') === false, $a['id']]
           <=>
           [strpos($b['countries'], 'EN') === false, $b['id']];
});

var_export($test);
```

PHP8 alternatives:

```
return [str_contains($b['countries'], 'EN'), $a['id']]
       <=>
       [str_contains($a['countries'], 'EN'), $b['id']];
```

or

```
return str_contains($b['countries'], 'EN') <=> [str_contains($a['countries'], 'EN')
       ?: $a['id']] <=> $b['id']];
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'countries' => 'EN,CH,SP',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'countries' => 'EN',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5,
    'countries' => 'SP,EN',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'countries' => 'SV,SP,EN',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 9,
    'countries' => 'RU,EN',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => 10,
    'countries' => 'EN,SP,IT',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => 12,
    'countries' => 'GR,EN',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'countries' => 'GE,SP,SV',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'countries' => 'PR,SP,IT',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
    'countries' => 'GE,SP',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'id' => 8,
    'countries' => 'FR',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'id' => 11,
    'countries' => 'SP,GR',
  ),
)
```

The array elements on either side of the spaceship operator are evaluated from left to right (leftside [0] vs rightside [0], then moving onto the pair of [1] values if there is a "tie" between the two [0] values).

If the `=== false` looks backwards, let me explain...

If `EN` is found in the countries string, the condition will evaluate as `false`. When comparing `true` and `false`, remember that `true` equates to 1 and `false` equates to 0.  We want ASC sorting, so we want to put false outcomes before true outcomes, ergo strings containing `EN` *need* to return false.  Hopefully that clears up the logic.