# Sorting PHP array using subkey-values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Erik] => Array
    ( 
        [count] => 10
        [changes] => 1
    )
    [Morten] => Array
    (
        [count] => 8
        [changes] => 1
    )
)
```

Now, the keys in the array are names of technicians in our Helpdesk-system. I'm trying to sort this based on number of `[count]` plus `[changes]` and then show them. I've tried to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/function.usort.php), but then the array keys are replaced by index numbers. How can I sort this and keep the array keys?

Comment: `uasort`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting multidimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059255/sorting-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `uasort` for this.

> bool uasort ( array &$array , callback
>   $cmp_function )
>
> This function sorts an array such that
>   array indices maintain their
>   correlation with the array elements
>   they are associated with, using a
>   user-defined comparison function.
>   This is used mainly when sorting
>   associative arrays where the actual
>   element order is significant.

Answer (score 10):

Try using uasort():

```
<?
function cmp($a, $b)
{
   return ($b['count'] + $b['changes']) - ($a['count'] + $a['changes']);
}

$arr = array(
   'John' => array('count' => 10, 'changes' => 1),
   'Martin' => array('count' => 5, 'changes' => 5),
   'Bob' => array('count' => 15, 'changes' => 5),
);

uasort($arr, "cmp");

print_r($arr);
?>
```

prints:

```
Array
(
   [Bob] => Array
   (
      [count] => 15
      [changes] => 5
   )
   [John] => Array
   (
      [count] => 10
      [changes] => 1
   )
   [Martin] => Array
   (
      [count] => 5
      [changes] => 5
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) which does exactly what you want (sort associative arrays mantaining the keys)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
uasort($array, create_function('$a, $b', 'return (array_sum($a) - array_sum($b));'));
```

That sorts an array using the [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function, and maintaining keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.i thin it works

```
function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a['count'] == $b['count']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['count'] > $b['count']) ? +1 : -1;
}

usort ( $array, 'cmp' );
```