# Array sorting in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

We have an array and need to sort the above array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 229
            [firstname] => ggg
            [lastname] => fff
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 230
            [firstname] => aaa
            [lastname] => jjj
        )

)
```

I want to sort the array as (Sort by firstname)

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 230 
            [firstname] => aaa
            [lastname] => jjj

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 229
            [name] => ggg
            [lastname] => fff
        )

)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124266/sort-object-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570146/sorting-php-array-using-subkey-values + several others.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort):

```
usort($ar, function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->firstname, $b->firstname);
});
```

Comment: +1, and in case of PHP < 5.3 use `usort($ar, create_function('$a,$b', 'return strcmp($a->firstname, $b->firstname);'));`. Or declare a function with a name use it.