# How can I sort an array based on date element?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array as follow in php. It contains of two array of std objects. 
How can I sort it based on report_date element?
as you see report_date is unix time.

```
Array(
[current] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [city_fa_name] => Ù…Ø´Ù‡Ø¯ Û³
                [report_date] => 1440963000
                [id] => 3
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [city_fa_name] => Ù…Ø´Ù‡Ø¯ Û³
                [report_date] => 1441049400
                [id] => 2
            )

    )

[saved] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [city_fa_name] => Ù…Ø´Ù‡Ø¯ Û³
                [report_date] => 1441049400
                [id] => 2
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [city_fa_name] => Ù…Ø´Ù‡Ø¯ Û³
                [report_date] => 1441135800
                [id] => 1
            )

    ))
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using ? You may put it on the tags.

Comment: You could try uasort. See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570146/sorting-php-array-using-subkey-values