# ksort a multidimensional array with two numeric keys

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, ksort

I expected this:

```
$f[14][5] = array('');
$f[13][1] = array('');
$f[13][3] = array('');
$f[13][2] = array('');
$f[14][1] = array('');
$f[13][2] = array('');
$f[14][2] = array('');
$f[14][4] = array('');
$f[14][3] = array(''); 
$f[13][4] = array('');
$f[13][5] = array('');


krsort($f);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($f);
```

to sort like

```
14 5, 
14 4, 
14 3, 
14 2,
14 1, 
13 5, 
13 4, 
13 3, 
13 2,
13 1
```

but it doesn't.
Somehow the second key is not sorted.

What is the most elegant short way to achieve this?

(investigated  usort in a manner like for instance in [Sorting multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059255/sorting-multidimensional-array-in-php) but I cannot find a way to target the second key)

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with [`krsort`](http://php.net/krsort) which sorts by keys in reversed order. You have also to loop over subarrays to sort them too because this function does not work on multidimentional arrays.

```
krsort($f);
foreach ($f as &$v) {
    krsort($v);
}
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  14 => 
    array (size=5)
      5 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
  13 => &
    array (size=5)
      5 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
```